# Can two locales shared the same script file paths in Adobe Configurator 2.0?

Tags: localization, adobe-indesign

I'm building a extension panel for InDesign using Adobe Configurator 2.0. For now, I'm supporting two locales: en_US and fr_CA. This is going well, I can set different locale-specific labels on my buttons, etc. The problem is that I also have to set locale-specific Script File paths for those buttons that execute a javascript file on click. Is it possible to have all locales share the same path for a button?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `Script File` paths are not shared by all locales, but `Script`s are. So I can simply use `Script`s and have them execute a file with

```
app.doScript(File(...), ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT);
```

This way, the same script is launched for every locale...